# Publish Joint position step by step

Tags: ros, topic, publisher, messages, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,
I need an advice about how to perform my robot simulation. I have a node that subscribe a topic and use the data subscribed to create a vector with all the angle that a joint has to reach through the final joint angle. I have three different joints, which is the best message to publish that contains the three joint angles? How can I publish them step by step. How can I make the second node that subscribe these joint angles?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252639/publish-joint-position-step-by-step/) by [nikkk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29066/nikkk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to create a URDF description of your robot, with *links* and *joints* for any moving or fixed relationships between the various reference frames. Then you should launch `robot_state_publisher` and `joint_state_publisher` to supply frame transformations as requested. In particular, you should configure `joint_state_publisher` to listen for the topics on which you will publish the joint states.

Presumably you'll either write a custom node or use a package like `moveit` to calculate and publish the required joint angles.

To actually perform the joint movements, you'll need a custom node that listens for the joint states and talks to your hardware, unless there is an appropriate package already available.

You should probably read these:

- [URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials): read the `tf` tutorial and then 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, and 4.5.
- [robot_state_publisher documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher)
- [joint_state_publisher documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2017-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5